# Contains any word of string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I trying to get from Database any name or tag that match any of words from string.
Something like search.

Example:

> Query: "Any query that matches"

I have first table with Name, and second with Tags for First Table.

I need something like this, not performance heavy. This will not work because Contains check whole string.

```
_db.Tag_Table.Where(t => t.First_Table.Name.Contains(query) || 
t.Tag_Table.Value.Contains(query))
                .Select(s => s.First_Table).ToList();
```

Any reasonable solution for this.

Comment: This question is a wee bit general to be answered defenitvely. This smells like an XY problem, so I recommend you post your actual requirements. Depending on your DBMS, a full text index might be what you need. Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for SQL Server FTIs.

Comment: Does it need to do the substring 'contains' match on words in Tag_Table?. It would be much more efficient if you can match whole words from Tag_Table to each of the items from the search string. That I believe will just translate to an 'Name in (...)' clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found solution, it returns correct results I think.

```
var queryList = query.Split(' ');

_db.Post.Where(f => queryList.Any(q => f.Title.Contains(q)) || queryList.Any(l => f.Tags.Any(t => t.Tag.Value.Contains(l))));
```

In every post, for every Query word I'm searching in Post Title or Every Tag Name in Tags Table. I'm returning result if I have Query word in title or in tag.

Thank you for your answers. 
It sounds that @Zeeshan Adil 2nd answer is similar.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this and let me know if it worked in comments:

```
 string[] terms = Query.Split(' ');
 string[] Results;

 string[] all = (from x in _db.Tag_Table
                    select x.Name).ToArray();

 Results =(from z in all
                       from w in terms 
                       where z.Contains(w)
                       select z).Distinct().ToArray();
```

**Edit**

also please try this:

```
string Query = "some value";
string[] terms = Query.Split(' ');


from x in _db.Tag_Table
           where terms.Any(val => p.First_Table.Name.Contains(val))
           select x;
```

Comment: You are performing an in-memory search for a DB column with an unknown (and potentially large) number of entries. That's something the the DB can surely do better.

Comment: @Sefe I just edited the answer and added another solution but I'm not sure about that, what do you think of that?

Comment: This will be performed in DB now (I assume you have tried the code and it works). As for the performance issue, it's hard to tell. The question is vague and for a good answer I think we'd need more information.

Comment: @Sefe Looking forward to more information by the guy

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil I posted solution that returns correct results. I don't know about performance. I think that I will not have too much Posts.

Comment: @Sefe I will read link that you posted. Can I do it faster with FTIs? But I have Tags  Table that contains Post Id, and Tag Id. I must search for every Tag in Tags table.